# $state.go reload and update URL with dynamic parameters

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In a controller, I'm calling:

```
$state.go("myState", $scope.urlParams);
```

`$scope.urlParams` can contains one or many params. (dynamic)

My `$stateProvider` config is like this:

```
url: '/myPage?param1&param2&param3&param4'
```

Now let's take an example to illustrate my problem:

I'm loading 'myPage' for the first time using:

```
$state.go("myState", $scope.urlParams);
```

with `$scope.urlParams = {'param1' : 111 , 'param2' : 222};`

My URL looks like this `..../myPage?param1=111&param2=222`

Now I'm already on 'myPage' but I'm using this time :

```
$state.go("myState", $scope.urlParams);
```

with `$scope.urlParams = {'param1' : 111};`

**My problem is there**, my url **still** looks like this `..../myPage?param1=111&param2=222`

But I want that, my URL looks like this:

```
..../myPage?param1=111
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the second time, you should change your code to:

```
$state.go("myState", $scope.urlParams, {inherit: false});
```

`$state.go` calls `$state.transitionTo` internally but automatically sets options to `{ location: true, inherit: true, relative: $state.$current, notify: true }`.

And the `inherit` property when set to `true` inherit URL parameters from current URL. That is why you are getting the previous parameters in the URL.

See the [docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state#methods_go).

Answer (score 0):

Set the inherit property to false in your $state.go() parameter.

```
$state.go("myState", $scope.urlParams, {inherit: false});
```

By default its true and it inherits the url parameters from your current url.

Answer (score -1):

You should do it with: `{reload:true}` properties, like that:

```
$state.go("resultSearchArticle", $scope.urlParams, {reload : true});
```